# Validation and Backspace Conflict Firefox

Tags: javascript, validation, input, keycode, backspace

I have an input field that has a validation. The validation works great in all browsers. However in Firefox there seems to be an issue. If an user presses backspace or arrow or home keys in that input field it simply does not work.

THE HTML:

```
<input onkeydown="return isName(event)" class="form-control firstnameweb_text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstname_text" name="firstname_text" onblur="isEmptyfname(this)" required="" type="text">
```

THE JS:

```
function isName(e, t) {
try {
    if (window.event) {
        var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else if (e) {
        var charCode = e.which;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode > 7 && charCode < 10) || (charCode == 46) || (charCode > 38 && charCode < 39) || (charCode == 32) || (charCode == 190))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.Description);
}};
```